# 16 channel output under linux

Tags: audacity, playback, multichannel, behringer, linux

I am a linux user and have recently purchased a Behringer XR-18 digital mixer that I want to record and play back on.  I am using audacity to record and it works just fine so my Fedora Linux laptop can see the full 18 channel USB audio interface.

I would like to play back the 18 track recording as 18 seaparate tracks back to the XR-18 so I can use its digital mixer capabilities like EQ, compression and effects to mix down my recording.  Is this possible under Linux?

When I try with audacity, it only sees a stereo 2 track output device and outputs the 18 tracks mixed down to stereo.

Is there some other playback program that can load up 18 (16?) tracks and play them back as separate tracks via USB?

Thanks
RLH

Comment: Have you tried with Ardour ? https://ardour.org/

Answer (score 1):

Ardour should have little enough problem with that.  It's basically the 500lb gorilla of Free Software audio work stations.  I'll assume that there is a reason you are a Linux user: while there are a few proprietary offers for Linux as well by now, one usually picks Linux as a reasoned tradeoff, to get rid of all the nuisances of proprietary software refusing to work or upgrade or interoperate or even get updated anymore.  And Ardour tends to be a good fit within that frame of choosing Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using reaper. which has experimental support for linux at this time.